# How to use a Java GUI designer for Clojure?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, clojure, gui-designer

I'm LOVING coding with Clojure. It's a great language! But until the moment I haven't found any GUI designer for Clojure (with drag and drop components such as Visual Studio's Form Designer, etc). I'm studying programming and my teachers are used to require we do forms. Sometimes the forms are very simple, sometimes more complex.

What I really want to know is: **What's the best way to integrate Clojure code within a Java Swing project?** I know all that stuff off using jars from compiled Clojure code, but it doesn't seem the right way to do it (coding Clojure, compiling it than using it in the Java project).

I usually use NetBeans for Java projects and Atom + proto-repl for Clojure.

Thank you! (and sorry for any English mistake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use seesaw (https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/tree/develop). It is not a GUI designer, only a library/DSL for constructing user interfaces in Clojure build on swing but in clojure, because of REPL, is very easy to develop gui interface interactively (see the tutorial https://gist.github.com/daveray/1441520)

Comment: I actually saw this same tutorial. But I was wondering: how would it be develop and maintain a single frame with a hundred components? Is it realistic to edit the position and display of so many components manually? And more: what if you had tens of frames? There's ERP systems built "fully" to work with frames. Would it be reasonable to make this sort of thing using just the REPL? By the way, thank you for the answer!